# Float became 0.0000 when fetched from core data

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I created an entity with a float attribute and set it's value to 0.5

```
+(void)createSportNamed:(NSString *)name withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
Sport *newSport = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sport" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newSport.name = name;
    newSport.maxRep = [NSNumber numberWithInt:45];
    newSport.endurance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f];
    NSLog(@"endurance at set = %f",[newSport.endurance floatValue]);

NSError *saveError = nil;
[context save:&saveError];
}
```

From the log, the value of the float is still 0.5000

But when I fetch it later on, the value somehow became 0.0000

```
-(NSArray*)createWorkoutForSport:(NSString*)sportName withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sport" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSPredicate *sportNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %d",sportName];
request.predicate = sportNamePredicate;
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
Sport *theFetchedSport = [results lastObject];

int totalRep = [[theFetchedSport maxRep]intValue];
float endure = [[theFetchedSport endurance]floatValue];
int set;
NSLog(@"Endurance = %f",endure);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+(void)createSportNamed:(NSString *)name withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
  Sport *newSport = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sport" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  newSport.name = name;
```

This clearly shows that the "name" field of your Sport entity is a string.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %d",sportName]
```

And yet here you are using `%d`, which means `int`.  You're casting a string pointer to an int.  You should be using `%@`.  Thus, your fetch request is returning an empty array, and `-lastObject` is returning `nil`, which means that `[nil endurance]` is also `nil`, which means that `[[nil endurance] floatValue]` is also `nil`, or `0`.